# Grey Background Above Main Content in Android Because of Margin

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I can't seem to get rid of this grey bar because of my margin in the below XML that is set to the ActionBar height.  Eventually an actionbar appears but transparent but how do I get rid of this grey background from the start?  If I use paddingTop then my actionbar is not clickable.

[image]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/action_bar"
            layout="@layout/action_bar" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` parent for all other layouts inside your Drawer.
And set the FrameLayout to stay below the appBar, like that:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/action_bar"
                layout="@layout/action_bar" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/action_bar_container" />

        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This should work, it should move the frame layout below the action bar only if it's visible!

Comment: Or just a LinearLayout

Comment: This worked but had to make `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for actionbar container and move ListView out for drawer.

Comment: Sorry, didn't checked that, just copy-pasted your code and added the parent layout

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) can help you... 
or try to add custom toolbar... make a separate layout file with the content like below`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/gradient"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

`
and include it with [include](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) tag in your drawer layout... Get the toolbar by findViewById(...) and set it using setSupportActionBar(Toolbar toolbar) method.